# Natural Exponential family with polynomial partition function

Tags: mathematical-statistics, exponential-family, example

Consider a natural exponential family:
\begin{equation}
f(x|\theta) = h(x) e^{ x \theta -A(\theta) }
\end{equation}
We assume that we are supported on $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e., $h(x)>0$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$).

My question: Are there some interesting (i.e., used) examples when $A(\theta)$ is a polynomial?

For example, if $A(\theta) = \theta^2/2$, then we get the normal distribution.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_exponential_family points out some others, albeit with different supports.

Comment: This [1990 paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journalArticle/Download?urlId=10.1214%2Faos%2F1176347491) by Mora and Letac could be related.

Comment: Is there some reason why you are requiring $h(x) > 0$ for all real $x$? If you impose that requirement, then the normal distribution is the only example with polynomial $A(\theta)$. $A(\theta)$ has to be convex, and polynomials are not usually convex, so there are only a few special cases of polynomial partition functions and the non-normal examples need the range of $x$ to be restricted.

Comment: @GordonSmyth thanks. That's a very good point. This basically closes this question.